# Search multiple patterns[separated by newline] in the same text line using grep

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a text file which looks like :

```
12345  12-02-2013 05:12:23:234 searchPeople service called by the follwoing input :
       name      : Tom
       id        : 12345
       regd_no   : REGD1234
12346  12-02-2013 05:12:23:240 response obtained from searchPeople service
```

I need to search multiple patterns : "name      : Tom" and "regd_no   : REGD1234" with grep.

Can anyboy help me please??

Answer (score 1):

Since this is your first question, try:

```
$ grep 'name\|regd_no' input.txt
       name      : Tom
       regd_no   : REGD1234
```

But in the future, please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)...

**update**

grep generally works on one-line at a time, but since your example-file is short, one approach to solve your problem is this:

```
$ tr -d '\n' < input.txt | grep -o 'name\s*:\s*Tom\|regd_no\s*:\s*REGD1234'
name      : Tom
regd_no   : REGD1234
```

Comment: This is true if name=Tom OR regd_no=REGD1234. If i want to do name=Tom AND regd_no=REGD1234